# How do I create a button in flash that can only be pressed on specific frames? (AS2)

Tags: flash, animation, button

For example, I have a blinking light animation that I want to be pressed, but only when the light is on. How would I go about doing this? I have the button inside a movie clip animation, and it's all ActionScript 2.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do this, I just forgot that I could use the _root command in AS2. Incase anyone needs to have this same question answered, just use this code in AS2 on your button.

```
on(release){
    _root.gotoAndStop("Puzzle 2");
}
```